# MySql count of rows and insert into the table that count

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a scenario where i need to take count of rows in mysql table for the current branch(in that table we are store branch) and insert the count of rows with other details into the same table. But the problem is when two or more concurrent users try to insert from the same branch at the same time the count is same for all the users, but for me the insert should not happ for the other user(s) until i read the count and insert that one user request . Is there any way the locking works for this and any example would be helpful(All i need to do this in MySql store procedure)

Edit : Sorry, I cant share the working code but i can write example here

My table structure is here

```
id    name    branchid    count
1     abc     1           1
2     xyz     1           2
3     abcd    2           1
4     wxyz    2           2
```

Here am taking count of rows from the above table for given branch(ex : 1) and inserting the row with that calculated count

Ex :

```
set @count = (select count(id) from tbl where branchid = 1);
```

later

```
insert into tbl(id, name, branchid, count)
values(5, 'abcd', 1, @count)
```

This works great provided if only **one user access this from one branch , but if more than one user from same branch** try to access this at exact same time the

```
@count
```

is duplicating for the branch users.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot work in the dark.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware edited my question

Comment: You could lock the table you read from until after you've stored the count. That way any second user, wanting to do the same computation, has got to wait for the first to finish.

Comment: Can i do that? Because while locking a table for reading will it allow me to write and release lock after write?

Comment: Yes you can lock a table, or even multiple tables. But do check whether your DB engine supports it. InnoDB does, for instance. PS: I was assuming you read from one table and wrote to another.

Comment: Thanks but accoridng to this link it throws an error [MySql Read Write Lock](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/). Any links would be helpful

Comment: Only when you try to write to a table you locked for reading. As I said: I was assuming you read from one table and wrote to another. If it is the same table you lock it for writing.

Comment: This is what transactions are for (which complete table locking is a very brute form of). You should add if you are using transactions at all in your app (and an engine that supports this, namely InnoDB). If yes, using "... where branchid = 1 for update);" should suffice (preferable with an index on `branch` to reduce the chance of a deadlock), if not, you may have to do some rework.

Comment: @Solarflare this particular piece of code, the previous guys haven't used transaction...ufff

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it in one query:

```
insert into tbl(id, name, branchid, count)
select 5, 'abcd', 1, count(*)
from from tbl 
where branchid = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks will give a try